# upgrade alfresco from 4.2.e to 5.0.c

Tags: alfresco

I have managed to upgrade my alfresco instalaltion to 5.0.c comuunity version. i am using centos 6.5 64bit.

steps I have taken

- Update java and mysql
- stop server alfresco
- create mysqldump
- tar contentstore
- tar shared
- mv them all to /opt
- copy tomcat/shared/lib
- tar tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco
- copy tomcat/shared/classes/global.properties
- uninstall old version of alfresco
- install new version of alfresco.
  get mysql driver http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and place in tomcat/shared/lib, may have to start alfresco then stop it to extract war files.
- copy all other jar files to tomcat/shared/lib
- drop alfresco db
- restore old version
- modify global properties file and resotre any other files, classes dir etc
- modify JAVA_OPTS in tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

  `JAVA_OPTS = "$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms4G -Xmx16G -XX:MaxPermSize=4G -Xss512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:NewSize=1G -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco-5.0.c -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2G"`
- start alfresco

I had solr index problem so i rebuilt solr4 as i was using lucene before using this guide http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr-reindex.html

I am seing the following repeatedly appear in the log file

`Mar 19, 2015 6:02:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [wcapiServlet] in context with path [/alfresco] threw exception
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02190075 Transaction must be active and synchronization is required: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-4,5,main]
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil.registerSynchronizations(TransactionSupportUtil.java:188)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil.getSynchronization(TransactionSupportUtil.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil.getResource(TransactionSupportUtil.java:147)
    at org.alfresco.util.cache.AbstractAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.getTransactionData(AbstractAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.java:260)
    at org.alfresco.util.cache.AbstractAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.isUpToDate(AbstractAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.java:315)
    at org.alfresco.repo.cache.AbstractMTAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.isUpToDate(AbstractMTAsynchronouslyRefreshedCache.java:90)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TenantRepositoryContainer.getRegistry(TenantRepositoryContainer.java:74)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy269.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:125)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy269.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Is there a `caused by` for that exception?

Comment: it appears while i try to browse